# for what input is this method going to crash

Tags: java, testing

looking for possible inputs to make this method compile but crash  at runtime.

Any suggestions?

```
public static void method1(Integer n)
{
    System.out.println(n.byteValue());
}
```

Comment: What values have you tried already?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

n == null will crash the method.